# IOS Custom UIView with XIB and fixed size

Tags: ios, swift, interface

is it possible to set the size of a custom UIView with a XIB design according to the fixed size of the XIB?

Background: if you want to initialize a UIView by code, one have to call the method initwithframe. However, i want, that the frame of the custom UIView is set to the size, specified in the xib, regardless of its parent frame or screen size.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your custom uiview has a fixed width and fixed height size, you only have to specify the x and y position in the Storyboard. Furthermore you will get an layout error in the Storyboard because it needs to have an height and width constraint. Since you already have that, click on your UIView and set the intristic size, that option you have beneath content compression, to ‘placeholder’. That way, you get no errors and when the viewcontrollers load, your uiview will resize to the specified width and height

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it is not about the Storyboard but the initiating and adding the view by code.